# Animate position when using js doesn't work, what do I need to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I have this script which gets fixed when scrolling down 120px. Works great.

But I also need to get my sidebar be default position:absolute; with margin:0;
AND when scrolling down 120px the sidebar class needs to be position:fixed; and margin-top:50px; I don't think it will be hard to do but I'm not a coder. Can someone help me please?

This doesn't work, for the margin it does but not position, because it can't animate? I can't find any solution yet..

```
$('.sidebar').animate({'position':'fixed'});
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var startY = 120;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    checkY();
  });
  function checkY(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
      $('.fixedDiv').slideDown(400, function(){});
    }else{
      $('.fixedDiv').slideUp(400, function(){});
    }
  }
  checkY();
});
```

Comment: Um... how exactly does one animate a transition between "fixed" and... "not fixed"?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol — It sounds like it is supported to be between "fixed" and "fixed" which makes even less sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to just do `$(".sidebar").css("position","fixed")` to set the CSS. `position` is not a property that can be animated, because it is nonsensical to try and do so.

Comment: ahhh ok .css it is :)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot set Position of Dom Using animation we need to use
dom.css('property', value);

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it like this because of some responsive stuff going on:

```
$('.sidebar').addClass('gofix');
```

and added css:

```
<style>
    .gofix{position:fixed; top:55px;}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .gofix{position:relative; top:auto;}
}
</style>
```